# I'm creating a list of objects from a files in a directory. How do i nest "subpage" objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, readdir

Creating a list of "page" objects from a file system. which looks like

```
pages/
- Home.jsx
- Blog.jsx
- Post.Blog.jsx
- Posts.Blog.jsx
- private/
-- Admin.jsx
-- Dashboard.jsx
-- admin/
--- Main.Admin.jsx
-- author/
--- Post.Admin.jsx
-- editor/
--- Editor.Admin.jsx
```

1. For Filenames with single name before the extension, I want to return objects that look like:

```
{name:"Home", isPrivate:false, permission:"guest"}
```

2. for Dot separated names outside of the private directory, I want to look like:

```
{name:"Blog", isPrivate:false permission:"guest", subpages:[{name:"Post", isPrivate:false, permission:"guest"},{name:"Posts", isPrivate:false, permission:"guest"},...]}
```

3. For Files inside of the Private will have the "isPrivate" key/val pair set to true, the "permission" key/val set to the subdirectory it lives in. for example:

```
{name:Admin, isPrivate:true permission:"private", subpages:[{name:"Post",isPrivate:true, permission:"author"},{name:"Main", isPrivate:true, permission:"admin"},...]}
```

I've tried for loops inside of the conditional to add subpages to the current page object being created but that caused issues when I tried to use recursion at that level to access the files in the private directory or its subfolders, so i broke it back down to this and am trying to build up from here.

```
 const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
    const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)
    const directoryPath = join(__dirname,'../../../../ui/src/pages')
    const files = []
    const createList = (dir)=>{
        const fileMatrix = fs.readdirSync(dir)
        fileMatrix.map(file=>{
            const filePath = join(dir,file)
            const stats = fs.statSync(filePath) 
            const isDir = stats.isDirectory()
            const isPrivate = filePath.includes('private')
            const permission = isPrivate ? path.dirname(filePath).split('/').pop():"guest"
            const fileParts = path.basename(filePath,'.jsx').split('.')
            const fileName = fileParts[0]
            const parent = fileParts[1]
            if (!isDir){
                file = {
                    name:fileName,
                    isPrivate,
                    permission
                }
                console.log(file)
            }
            else if(isDir){
                createList(filePath)
            }
        })
    }
       
      createList(directoryPath);
```

Comment: How deep is this file tree going to go? If it's just these three levels with the rather hardcoded/specific specification, you probably don't need recursion. I'd also tackle issues 2 and 3 in isolation--they seem like fundamentally different specifications. For context, are you creating a static site generator or...?

Comment: The hierarchy is dictated by the dot separated name of the file. so if the file has 3 dot separated names then it is 3 levels deep. I use "fileParts.length" to determine how deep the current item should be nested. the recursion is for retrieving all files from each folder nested in the directory. Not really a site generator just using a different approach to render existing pages.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show an example with a few layers deep to help motivate the recursion? It's not clear to me how that'd look. As for "just using a different approach", the strategy here seems rather unusual, so you might want to explain the use case a bit more, because there could be a pretty standard, straightforward approach to whatever your fundamental problem is that you may be overlooking.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to build another recursive function to target the parent array and push the child objects into it.

Comment: Great. Feel free to post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help others with the same problem.